# How to run chrome extension in specific domain

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

Is there a way to limit a Chrome extension to only run on certain urls?

I build an extension that I won't to run only inside specific facebook app.
https://apps.facebook.com/appname/*

The extension add option to 'Right click menu' when clicking on image

How can I do that ?

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "profiler",
  "description": "Show user profile page",
  "version": "0.2",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["dating.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon.png",
    "48": "icon.png",
    "128": "icon.png"
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

To add a menu option that shows only for images on a specific domain you can do the following:

On your manifest:

```
"permissions": [
    "contextMenus"
],
```

On your background script:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create( { 
    title: 'My Menu Item',
    contexts: ['image'],
    documentUrlPatterns: ['https://apps.facebook.com/appname/*'],
    onClick: function( info, tab ) {
    ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Does the downvoter care for a comment explaining the downvote ?